# How to save camera image when needed?

Tags: ros, gazebo, image-raw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently following this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Camera) to publish image messages using the camera plugin. I can totally subscribe the image_raw topic and save every published image message, but that's not what I need.

I am using gazebo to collect image dataset of object manipulation. So ideally I need to capture (save to file) one image after some manipulation actions, then continue with the next round of manipulation and image capturing. So it is like a service request to save the image when needed rather than save images all the time. However, the only source of image I know in gazebo is the image topic. Does anyone have a better idea on how to do that?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264490/how-to-save-camera-image-when-needed?/) by [wy3](https://answers.ros.org/users/30862/wy3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One option would be to use `ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)` ([docs](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wy3](https://answers.ros.org/users/30862/wy3/) on 2017-06-26**:
Thank you! Work like a charm.

**Comment by [houhao](https://answers.ros.org/users/66924/houhao/) on 2021-06-09**:
Hello, i was wondering how to update the msg content? I used this waitForMessage in a for loop but every time i call it, the msg content seems the same. Basically, I just tried to save the image when moving to a new position. Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-09**:
Please do not post follow-up questions in comments under 5 year old questions with accepted answers. This has almost zero visibility. Post a new question instead.

But as a quick comment: if used correctly, `waitForMessage(..)` will return new messages each time. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Please include more detail about how you're calling the function in your new post.